# fileinfo_open() Fatal error

Tags: php

i am using PHP 5.3 and i have checked that my fileinfo is enabled. But when i run my code its occurring an error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   function finfo_open()

Anyone can help me to fixed this, here is my code.

```
$mime=finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME,filename);
        echo "File Type is: ".$mime;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "filename" needs to be a file that contains a "MIME magic" database. If you want to determine the type of file, you first need to open the MIME database, *then* ask that database to identify the file.

For instance, if the MIME database is stored in `/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc` (most Linux distributions store it there), you can do:

```
// open MIME database
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME, "/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc");
if (!$finfo)
    die("error opening MIME info database");

// print out MIME information of "some-file-name-here"
echo finfo_file($finfo, "some-file-name-here");

finfo_close($finfo);
```

However, if this is a virtual hosting provider, you might need to copy the `magic.mgc` file into your public web directory.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is irrelevant now because the asker updated his question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing some configuration in php.ini. Either you don't have extentions (or dynamic libraries) turned on or as suggestet [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.configuration.php) a line in php.ini.

Checklist:

- Is there a line in your php.ini `enable_dl = On`?
- Do you have a line `extension=fileinfo.so`?

Comment: I checked my php.ini file and enable_dl = On i found this and extension=php_fileinfo.dll instead of extension=fileinfo.so

Comment: you are working on windows then... Did you restart your apache server after installing the extention?